# How to avoid exit from fullscreen on browser when refresh page?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Is there method to avoid exit from fullscreen when a web page gets refreshed?

What i tried so far

I've used javascripts `toggleFullScreen()` function via `onclick` Handler on a button to set view on fullscreen mod.

But when the page got refreshed (using F5 key) it will exit from fullscreen mod. As I noticed in browsers (press f11 to fullscreen), when refresh while in fullscreen mod it doesn't get exit from fullscreen mod.

Question:

> Is there any option to stop exiting fullscreen mod in case of a refresh if it got triggerd manually using `toggleFullScreen()`?

Comment: thats 2 different fullscreens that you are talking about

Comment: Try requesting fullscreen on page load, if that works, then you can look for a way to store a flag when the user goes fullscreen, which you can later check after the page refresh with the page load code I mentioned. Something like SessionStorage should do the job.

Comment: No there is no way. The fullscreen API (`Element.requestFullcreen`) requires an user-interaction. When your document reloads, all its state reloads too, and the required user-interaction you got is just lost. Possible workarounds from less horrible to please don't do that are: let it like that, force a splash screen requiring user-click on reload, try to prevent reloading...